# How Can I sort and split my validated Excel Data into Sheets with VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, validation

I have a large amount of data in 5 columns. I need to do the following based on column E (file path):

- verify the path is valid, if not try a secondary path and return the correct one, or an error value if neither are valid
- if there is a valid path, get the file size (size should be >0 )
- if there is a valid path, get the file extension (there are lots of "bad" extensions like nothing at all, a period with nothing after it, pdf[1], pdf, etc...) I can create a whitelist for which are "good".

Once this is complete, I need to make one new sheet per file extension, and copy over the first 4 columns plus the valid path into the 5th column. There should be a "bad data" sheet as well for everything that didn't get "validated" as per above. On the original sheet, if it would be possible to create another column mapping to the new location of that row it would be great, but not required.
Hopefully this example will make it a little more clear. I am using Excel 2010, the google spreadsheet is just for a visual example.

Here is my sample data: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/127H7WRwHljYWX-46AAjzBrOvAlXkh4OcAF6jflaT-lI/edit#gid=0

I have functions for the first three items, but the last with moving the data around I'm not sure how to accomplish.

Here is a link to my 3 functions: http://pastebin.com/afRMgvTE

```
Private Function FileExists(ByVal sPathName As String, Optional ByVal sPathName2 As String) As String
    On Error Resume Next
    If sPathName <> "" Then
        If Dir$(sPathName) <> "" Then
            FileExists = sPathName
        ElseIf sPathName2 <> "" And Dir$(sPathName2) <> "" Then
            FileExists = sPathName2
        Else
            FileExists = "NO VALID URL"
        End If
    End If
End Function

Private Function GetFileSize(ByVal sPathName As String) As Long
    On Error Resume Next
    GetFileSize = FileLen(sPathName)
End Function

Private Function GetFileExt(ByVal sPathName As String) As String
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim fso As New Scripting.FileSystemObject
    Dim currentExtension As String

    currentExtension = fso.GetExtensionName(Trim(sPathName))

    Dim validExtension As Object
    Set validExtension = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    validExtension.Add "bmp", 1
    validExtension.Add "csv", 2
    validExtension.Add "doc", 3
    validExtension.Add "docm", 4
    validExtension.Add "docx", 5
    validExtension.Add "gif", 6
    validExtension.Add "htm", 7
    validExtension.Add "jpg", 8
    validExtension.Add "msg", 9
    validExtension.Add "pdf", 10
    validExtension.Add "ppt", 11
    validExtension.Add "rtf", 12
    validExtension.Add "tif", 13
    validExtension.Add "txt", 14
    validExtension.Add "vsd", 15
    validExtension.Add "xls", 16
    validExtension.Add "xlsm", 17
    validExtension.Add "xlsx", 18
    validExtension.Add "zip", 19

    If validExtension.Exists(LCase(currentExtension)) Then
        GetFileExt = currentExtension
    Else
        GetFileExt = "UNSUPPORTED"
    End If

End Function
```

Comment: With the example on line 7 - are you trying to check every file extention to see if it exists? For example, does \\path\file.bmp exist, if no check \\path\file.csv etc?

Comment: @AxGryndr no, I pass in two file paths. Long story short, the file will either be on \\server1\path1\file.txt or \\server2\path2\file.txt, the filename and path are not changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you were looking for something like this:

```
Sub PrintResults()

    Dim PathRange As Range, Temp As String, Cell As Range

    ' Make sure at least one path exists, and if so, find the range.
    On Error Resume Next
    Set PathRange = Intersect(Sheets("input").UsedRange, Sheets("input").UsedRange.Offset(1), Range("E:E"))
    On Error GoTo 0
    If PathRange Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    ' For every path
    For Each Cell In PathRange

        ' See if the path exists, and mark it, one way or another
        Temp = FileExists(Cell.Text): Cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = Temp
        If Temp = "No Valid Path" Then
            ' Note errors
            Temp = "error"
            Else
            ' If no error yet, then get size and extension
            Cell.Offset(0, 2).Value = GetFileSize(Temp)
            Temp = GetFileExt(Temp): Cell.Offset(0, 3).Value = Temp
            ' If there is an error with the extension note it
            If Temp = "blank" Then Temp = "error"
        End If
        If Temp = "error" Then Temp = "bad data"

        ' Note the location (its equal to the usedrange.rows count, because of the title row)
        Cell.Offset(0, 4).Value = """" & Temp & """ row " & Sheets(Temp).UsedRange.Rows.Count

        ' Copy the data
        Sheets("input").Range("A" & Cell.Row, Cell).Copy
        Sheets(Temp).Range("A1").Offset(Sheets(Temp).UsedRange.Rows.Count).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll
        Application.CutCopyMode = False

    Next Cell

End Sub
```

Comment: Ok before noting the location, I've added "CreateSheetIf (Temp)" to create the sheet for the categories if it doesn't exist yet.

Comment: But, the data always gets copied into row 2 (and it logs that it is in row 1) but it just keeps overwriting.

Comment: Ok I've fixed that by adding the column headers when I create the new sheets. Thanks!